# SQL Server 2014 Edition Downgrade

Tags: sql-server-2014, migration, standard-edition, downgrade

I have a SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition used by my devs to test their applications pointing to a common instance. Lately I've been informed that for this purpose I can use Developer Edition, that it would keep all the features they need to work.

I've see on Microsoft website that this counts as an Edition Downgrade and won't have a proper "Wizard" to help on this task. Seeing this, I planned on:

1. Backup all databases, export users, jobs and grants.
2. Uninstall Standard Edition.
3. Install Developer Edition.
4. Restore databases and re-create users, give grants and re-create jobs.

I did use DBA Tools Powershell Library to migrate a previous instance on the exact same case. Is this plan the easiest option to achieve this migration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event though it says its a downgrade, I would say its *kind of an upgrade* since Developer Edition is equivalent to enterprise in-terms of features.

A straight [`Start-DbaMigration`](https://dbatools.io/functions/start-dbamigration/) (from dbatools) will copy all stuff.

I would suggest to provision new machines and just use dbatools to migrate off and then decomm the old standard edition.

Just be aware, if in PROD you are using Standard Edition and your devs started using Enterprise features since they are available in Dev edition, then you will be in trouble as those wont work in PROD being in standard edition.

Comment: Hi Kin, on my case I would need to keep the same instance name, this command would work well when using different ones right? Changing instances name isn't a easy task right?

Comment: This environment isn't PROD, only test subjects are conducted there. Our PROD runs on Standard to keep the "paper stuff" right. :)

Comment: You can still go with new ones but use a dns alias once you cutover. Else you will have to uninstall and reinstall and then restore all dbs, logins, jobs, etc. more work for you. Also, I was making a point that - make sure your devs dont use Enterprise features in DEV since they wont work in PROD (as your PROD is standard edition).

Comment: Now I did understand Kin, thank you very much for the suggestion. Also, I'll make sure they get that in mind, and if really necessary we'll upgrade PROD to Enterprise.